# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: cpu

These are the recommended sys requirements:

2 GHz dual core processor or better
    2 GB system memory
    25 GB of free hard drive space
    Either a DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
    Internet access is helpful

I only have a dual core 1.4 GHz processor on my laptop, will I be able to operate Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS?

Comment: You already have the information you need, also processor speed is not as important as number of cores and RAM and disk.  See the linked duplicate for 'minimum specs' vs. 'recommended specs'.